# Error al enviar parámetros a borrar información en asp.net y sql

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

Hola muy buenas tardes apenitas comencé en asp.net y estoy haciendo un vil crud el detalle radica que cuando trato de hacer la sentencia borrar me aparece este detalle:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: 'Error de inicio de sesión. El inicio de sesión se realiza desde un dominio que no es de confianza y no se puede utilizar con autenticación de Windows.'
```

El problema radica en que la cadena de conexión al parecer está bien:

```
<connectionStrings>
        <add name="connDB" connectionString="Data Source = 192.168.xx.xx; Initial Catalog = Seic; User= sa; Password=Seicsa123; Integrated Security = True"/>
    </connectionStrings>
```

Lo que he checado es que la cadena de seguridad al parecer es correcta y al enviar la información o el id que quiero eliminar nomás no da

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el error que aparece al ejecutar el programa, ¿podrían apoyarme?

Comment: para poder ayudarte por favor muestra tu cadena de conexión

Comment: Por favor, no uses imágenes salvo que sea absolutamente necesario. Mira por favor [aca](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/3976/324). Los errores y tu codigo deben ir como texto formateado segun corresponda (si es un error como comentario, si es codigo como codigo),siempre.

Comment: Integrated Security usa credenciales **de Windows** y estás usando `sa`, por lo que asumo que quieres autenticar con un usuario de la BD. Debería ir en false. Yo comenzaría siempre por revisar la [documentación oficial](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/connection-string-syntax) para no suponer que la cadena de conexión es válida o no